# While dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I try to find the last colored cell of a column

I have this code which works inside sheet code :

```
Dim n As Integer: n = 0
While (Range("A" & n).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 255))
    n = n + 1
Wend
```

But when in my module, i replaced the 2nd line by :

```
While (Worksheets("MyWs").Range("A" & n).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255,  255))
```

And this line throw error 1004 object defined error

I also tried

```
While (Worksheets("MyWs").Range(Worksheets("MyWs").Cell(1,n)).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255,  255))
```

without success

Comment: Are you sure that this is the line throwing the error? I cannot reproduce your error with the same setting described in your question.

Comment: That first code snippet will not work: there's no `Range("A0")`. A row or column index can't be zero.

Comment: You need to change the value of `n` ... start `n` with `n = 1`

Answer (score 2):

Phoenix, you say you are trying to find the last **colored** cell. But in your condition, you are testing the cells against `RGB (255, 255, 255)` which is color **White**. You need to use an index or code for **No Fill** color which could look like this `.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`. So even if you were not getting these errors, your code would probably not work the way you intend to. I might be able to provide a solution to your problem.

Before I share the code, please let me note few things. Since I do not know how your data look like, I cannot tailor the code to your exact needs. This is a basic code using my favourite `For Each` loop but of course, you can use whatever loop you prefer.

The loop should start in colored cells and will continue until it encounters first non-colored cell. So if you have some non-colored cells "in the middle" of the column, it will stop the loop.

Please see the code below:

```
Sub find_last_colored()
Dim cel As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

'define the number of last row in which the cell is not empty
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'loop through every cell in column A to the last non-empty cell
For Each cel In ActiveSheet.Range("A:A" & lastRow)
    If cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        'activates the last colored cell and gives its address
        cel.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
        MsgBox cel.Offset(-1, 0).Address
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

You can notice I did not define exact scope of the ranges, I left it only as `ActiveSheet.` so do not forget to change that if needed.
I hope this solves your current problem or atleast sets you in right direction.

Comment: The "If" conditions doesn't work (immediatly true), but i understood your way of doing it, so i replaced it by the condition : `If ActiveSheet.Range(cel.address).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then`.
Works fine. Thanks